# wso2 is and esb UTF8

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Error installing IS

I am installing wso2 is MySql. 
MySQL is set to UTF-8. These are the errors:

1 :

```
CREATE INDEX REG_PATH_IND_BY_PATH_VALUE USING HASH ON REG_PATH(REG_PATH_VALUE, REG_TENANT_ID);
```

Error

```
 MySQL Database Error: Table '#sql-197b_412' uses an extension that doesn't exist in this MySQL version
```

2 :

```
CREATE TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE (
            AUTHORIZATION_CODE VARCHAR(255),
            CONSUMER_KEY VARCHAR(255),
            CALLBACK_URL VARCHAR(1024),
            SCOPE VARCHAR(2048),
            AUTHZ_USER VARCHAR(512),
            TIME_CREATED TIMESTAMP,
            VALIDITY_PERIOD BIGINT,
            PRIMARY KEY (AUTHORIZATION_CODE),
            FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS(CONSUMER_KEY) ON DELETE CASCADE
)TABLESPACE tb_regdb engine ndb storage disk;
```

Error:

```
MySQL Database Error: Got error 851 'Maximum 8052 bytes of FIXED columns supported, use varchar or COLUMN_FORMAT DYNAMIC instead' from NDBCLUSTER
```

wso2 can be installed on a database in UTF8?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a MySQL cluster with NDB engine. Therefore you need to run the MySQL script which can be found inside the `<IS_HOME>/dbscripts/mysql_cluster.sql`

In addition Identity Server also has identity scripts under `<IS_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/` and `IS_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/application-mgt/`. It have not shipped the identity script for mysql_cluster with NDB engine.

But you can modify the existing `mysql.sql` script under the `<IS_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/` and `IS_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/application-mgt/` and make them work for MySQL cluster. In `dbscripts/identity/mysql.sql` and `dbscripts/identity/application-mgt/mysql.sql` `ENGINE INNODB` clauses can be replaced with `ENGINE NDB`. The value of configuration option `MaxNoOfTriggers` had to be increased to avoid 4239 NDB errors.